# AssertionError: Tried to export a function which references untracked resource

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I wrote a unit-test in order to safe a model after noticing that I am not able to do so (anymore) during training.

```py
@pytest.mark.usefixtures("maybe_run_functions_eagerly")
def test_save_model(speech_model: Tuple[TransducerBase, SpeechFeaturesConfig]):
    model, speech_features_config = speech_model
    speech_features_config: SpeechFeaturesConfig
    channels = 3 if speech_features_config.add_delta_deltas else 1
    num_mel_bins = speech_features_config.num_mel_bins
    enc_inputs = np.random.rand(1, 50, num_mel_bins, channels)
    dec_inputs = np.expand_dims(np.random.randint(0, 25, size=10), axis=1)
    inputs = enc_inputs, dec_inputs
    model(inputs)

    # Throws KeyError:
    # graph = tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph()
    # tensor = graph.get_tensor_by_name("77040:0")

    directory = tempfile.mkdtemp(prefix=f"{model.__class__.__name__}_")
    try:
        model.save(directory)
    finally:
        shutil.rmtree(directory)
```

Trying to save the model will always throw the following error:

```
E         AssertionError: Tried to export a function which references untracked resource Tensor("77040:0", shape=(), dtype=resource). TensorFlow objects (e.g. tf.Variable) captured by functions must be tracked by assigning them to an attribute of a tracked object or assigned to an attribute of the main object directly.
E         
E         Trackable Python objects referring to this tensor (from gc.get_referrers, limited to two hops):
E         <tf.Variable 'transformer_transducer/transducer_encoder/inputs_embedding/convolution_stack/conv2d/kernel:0' shape=(3, 3, 3, 32) dtype=float32>
```

> **Note:** As you can see in the code above, but I am not able to retrieve this tensor with `tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("77040:0")`.
>
> I tried the following too, but the result is always empty:
>
> ```py
> model(batch)  # Build the model
>
> tensor_name = "77040"
>
> var_names = [var.name for var in model.trainable_weights]
> weights = list(filter(lambda var: tensor_name in var, var_names))
>
> var_names = [var.name for var in model.trainable_variables]
> variables = list(filter(lambda var: tensor_name in var, var_names))
>
> print(weights)
> print(variables)
> ```

The problem is that I do not understand why I am getting this because the affected layer *is* tracked by Keras as you can see in the screenshot below. I took it during a debug-session in the `call()` function.

[image]

I have no explanation for this and I am running out of ideas what the issue might be here.

The `transformations` list in the screenshot is a property of and getting constructed by a layer `InputsEmbedding` like so:

```py
class InputsEmbedding(layers.Layer, TimeReduction):
    def __init__(self, config: InputsEmbeddingConfig, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        if config.transformations is None or not len(config.transformations):
            raise RuntimeError("No transformations provided.")

        self.config = config

        self.transformations = list()
        for transformation in self.config.transformations:
            layer_name, layer_params = list(transformation.items())[0]
            layer = _get_layer(layer_name, layer_params)
            self.transformations.append(layer)

        self.init_time_reduction_layer()

    def get_config(self):
        return self.config.dict()


def _get_layer(name: str, params: dict) -> layers.Layer:
    if name == "conv2d_stack":
        return ConvolutionStack(**params)
    elif name == "stack_frames":
        return StackFrames(**params)
    else:
        raise RuntimeError(f"Unsupported or unknown time-reduction layer {name}")
```

---

In order to verify that the problem is not the `InputsEmbedding`, I created a unit-text for saving a model that is using just this particular layer.

```py
@pytest.mark.usefixtures("maybe_run_functions_eagerly")
def test_inputs_embedding_save_model():
    convolutions = [
        "filters=2, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(2, 1)",
        "filters=4, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(2, 1)",
        "filters=8, kernel_size=(3, 4), strides=(1, 1)",
    ]

    config = InputsEmbeddingConfig()
    config.transformations = [dict(conv2d_stack=dict(convolutions=convolutions)), dict(stack_frames=dict(n=2))]

    num_features = 8
    num_channels = 3

    inputs = layers.Input(shape=(None, num_features, num_channels))
    x = inputs
    x, _ = InputsEmbedding(config)(x)
    model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=x)
    model.build(input_shape=(1, 20, num_features, num_channels))

    directory = tempfile.mkdtemp(prefix=f"{model.__class__.__name__}_")
    try:
        model.save(directory)
    finally:
        shutil.rmtree(directory)
```

Here I am able to save this layer without any issues:

[image]

#### `ConvolutionStack`

As it seems to be relevant, here is the (rather ugly) implementation of `ConvolutionStack`:

```py
from typing import List

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import convolutional

from speech.lab.layers import InputsRequirements
from speech.lab.models import conv_util, models_util


class ConvolutionStack(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(
        self,
        convolutions: List[str],
        kernel_regularizer: dict = None,
        bias_regularizer: dict = None,
        **kwargs
    ):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.config = dict(
            convolutions=convolutions,
            kernel_regularizer=kernel_regularizer,
            bias_regularizer=bias_regularizer
        )
        self.conv_stack_config = [eval(f"dict({convolution})") for convolution in convolutions]
        self.conv_blocks = list()

        if kernel_regularizer is not None:
            kernel_regularizer = models_util.maybe_to_regularizer(kernel_regularizer)
        if bias_regularizer is not None:
            bias_regularizer = models_util.maybe_to_regularizer(bias_regularizer)

        for block_config in self.conv_stack_config:
            block = _new_convolution_block(
                **block_config,
                kernel_regularizer=kernel_regularizer,
                bias_regularizer=bias_regularizer,
            )
            self.conv_blocks.append(block)

        self.drop_dim2 = layers.Lambda(tf.squeeze, arguments=dict(axis=-2))
        self.expand_last = layers.Lambda(tf.expand_dims, arguments=dict(axis=-1))

    @property
    def inputs_requirements(self) -> InputsRequirements:
        requirements, frame_look_back = conv_util.get_conv2d_stack_requirements(self.conv_stack_config)
        first = requirements[0]
        t_min, f_size = first["min_size"]
        t_grow, f_grow = first["grow_size"]
        return InputsRequirements(
            frame_look_back=frame_look_back,
            t_min=t_min,
            t_grow=t_grow,
            f_min=f_size,
            f_grow=f_grow,
        )

    def call(self, inputs, training=None, mask=None, **kwargs):
        """
        :param inputs:
            Tensor taking the form [batch, time, freq, channel]
        :param training:
        :param mask:
        :param kwargs:
        :return:
            Tensor taking the form [batch, time, freq, 1]
        """

        if training:
            t_min = self.inputs_requirements.t_min
            t_grow = self.inputs_requirements.t_grow
            pad = conv_util.get_padding_for_loss(tf.shape(inputs)[1], t_min=t_min, t_grow=t_grow)
            inputs = tf.pad(inputs, ((0, 0), (0, pad), (0, 0), (0, 0)))

            if mask is not None:
                mask = tf.pad(mask, ((0, 0), (0, pad)))

        f_min = self.inputs_requirements.f_min
        f_grow = self.inputs_requirements.f_grow
        assert (inputs.shape[2] - f_min) % f_grow == 0, (
            f'Inputs dimension "freq" ' f"expected to be {f_min} + n * {f_grow}  but got {inputs.shape[2]} instead."
        )

        x = inputs
        for block in self.conv_blocks:

            for layer in block:

                if mask is not None and isinstance(layer, convolutional.Conv):
                    st, _ = layer.strides
                    kt = tf.maximum(layer.kernel_size[0] - 1, 1)
                    mask = mask[:, :-kt][:, ::st]
                    mask = tf.pad(mask, ((0, 0), (0, tf.maximum(2 - layer.kernel_size[0], 0))))

                x = layer(x, training=training)

        return self.expand_last(self.drop_dim2(x)), mask

    def get_config(self):
        return self.config


def _new_convolution_block(
    filters: int,
    kernel_size: tuple,
    strides: tuple,
    use_bias: bool = False,
    use_norm: bool = True,
    kernel_regularizer=None,
    bias_regularizer=None,
    activation=None,
):
    assert strides[0] % 2 == 0 or strides[0] == 1, "Strides on the time axis must be divisible by 2 or be exactly 1."

    if activation is not None:
        activation_layer = layers.Activation(activation)
    else:
        activation_layer = layers.Lambda(lambda x: x)

    if use_norm:
        norm_layer = layers.LayerNormalization()
    else:
        norm_layer = layers.Lambda(lambda x: x)

    return (
        layers.Conv2D(
            filters=filters,
            kernel_size=kernel_size,
            strides=strides,
            use_bias=use_bias,
            kernel_regularizer=kernel_regularizer,
            bias_regularizer=bias_regularizer,
        ),
        norm_layer,
        activation_layer,
    )
```

#### See also

- [tensorflow/serving #1719](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/issues/1719)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using

- tensorflow v2.5.0
- Python: 3.9

It appears that the problem occurs when we declare/define a layer as class-variable. I can only assume that the problem has to do with the internal Keras logic, which probably makes sense, but imo it's not obvious to the user and I don't think I have ever seen a hint pointing out that this can be an issue.

So, in my project I am having the following:

```py
class Model(keras.Model):
    inputs_embedding: InputsEmbedding = None  # <-- This caused the problem

    def __init__(config, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if config.embeddings is not None:
            self.inputs_embedding = InputsEmbedding(config.embeddings)
        # ...
```

### MVP Example

The following example creates instances of `ModelA`, `ModelB`, `ModelC` and `ModelD`. Model `A` and `B` can be saved but `C` cannot. From what I can tell, it does not work to declarea layer *which has trainable weights* as class-variable. However, it does seem to work for layers which do not have trainable weights (see `ModelB`).

Please note how `ModelD` can be saved though. The difference to `ModelB` is that the layer gets only declared and not defined as `None` which leads to the question why `ModelC` works though.

#### Source Code

```py
import tempfile

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers


class ModelA(tf.keras.Model):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.model_layer = layers.LayerNormalization()

    def call(self, inputs, training=None, mask=None):
        return self.model_layer(inputs)

    def get_config(self):
        return dict()


class ModelB(tf.keras.Model):
    model_layer: layers.Layer = None

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # This is probably working because layers.Lambda has no trainable variables
        self.model_layer = layers.Lambda(lambda x: x)

    def call(self, inputs, training=None, mask=None):
        return self.model_layer(inputs)

    def get_config(self):
        return dict()


class ModelC(tf.keras.Model):
    model_layer: layers.Layer = None

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.model_layer = layers.LayerNormalization()

    def call(self, inputs, training=None, mask=None):
        return self.model_layer(inputs)

    def get_config(self):
        return dict()


class ModelD(tf.keras.Model):
    model_layer: layers.Layer

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.model_layer = layers.LayerNormalization()

    def call(self, inputs, training=None, mask=None):
        return self.model_layer(inputs)

    def get_config(self):
        return dict()


def save_tmp_model(model: tf.keras.Model):
    name = model.__class__.__name__
    print(f'Saving model {name}')
    try:
        model.save(tempfile.mkdtemp(prefix=f"{name}_"))
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Unable to save model: {name}")
        print('Error message:')
        print(str(e))
        return

    print(f".. success!")


def main():
    inputs = np.random.rand(1, 50, 16)

    model_a = ModelA()
    model_b = ModelB()
    model_c = ModelC()
    model_d = ModelD()

    # Build models
    model_a(inputs)
    model_b(inputs)
    model_c(inputs)
    model_d(inputs)

    # Save models
    save_tmp_model(model_a)
    save_tmp_model(model_b)
    save_tmp_model(model_c)
    save_tmp_model(model_d)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

#### Output

```
Saving model ModelA
.. success!
Saving model ModelB
.. success!
Saving model ModelC
Unable to save model: ModelC
Error message:
Tried to export a function which references untracked resource Tensor("1198:0", shape=(), dtype=resource). TensorFlow objects (e.g. tf.Variable) captured by functions must be tracked by assigning them to an attribute of a tracked object or assigned to an attribute of the main object directly.

Trackable Python objects referring to this tensor (from gc.get_referrers, limited to two hops):
<tf.Variable 'model_c/layer_normalization_1/gamma:0' shape=(16,) dtype=float32>
Saving model ModelD
.. success!
```

Comment: Thank you very much for providing such a clean code to reproduce the issue and understand its behavior

Comment: No problem. I hope it helps the next poor guy who runs into this issue. It was quite well hidden an the error message was not helpful at all. ^^

Comment: I think this is because keras layer does not keep track of class property, but  it does track instance property, so when I added an useless `self.tmp = self.model_layer` in `__init__`, we can save it without problem.

Comment: I think it makes sense to not have a reference as a class property. Also in your example fixes, you don't really have one either, since with `self.model_layer = ...` you're not overwriting the class property, but just setting an instance property.

I'm having this issue myself, without having any class property defined...

Answer (score 4):

Your issue is not related to `'transformer_transducer/transducer_encoder/inputs_embedding/ convolution_stack/conv2d/kernel:0'`. 
The error code tells you this element is referring to a non trackable element. It seems the non-trackable object is not directly assigned to an attribute of this conv2d/kernel:0.

To solve your issue, we need to localize `Tensor("77040:0", shape=(), dtype=resource)` from this error code:

```
AssertionError: Tried to export a function which references untracked resource\
Tensor("77040:0", shape=(), dtype=resource). 
TensorFlow objects (e.g. tf.Variable) captured by functions must be tracked by assigning them to an attribute of a tracked object or assigned to an attribute of the main object directly.
```

##### Edit:

Thanks to your comments, we found that "ConvolutionStack" seems to reproduce the error.

> The problem only occurs if I use the ConvolutionStack layer in InputsEmbedding but I can save both of them successfully in a standalone model.

I understand you cannot share the config of this layer and that's why I suggest you try and localize this `Tensor(77040:0` from the ConvolutionStack.

This untrackable tensor must be an artifcat or a temporary tensor created by a process of a function of ConvolutionStack.

Try to find a tensor that could be passed from a function to another instead of being assigned to an attribute of a layer's class

Comment: I feel like a noob asking this but how can I localize that tensor?

Comment: @StefanFalk Could you provide the config of the layer `conv2d/kernel:0`

Comment: `conv2d` is just a `tf.keras.layers.Conv2D`-layer.

Comment: Take a look at the unit-test `test_inputs_embedding_save_model()`. All `InputsEmbedding` does is apply these convolutions by using the Keras `Conv2D` layer. And, as seen in the test, I am able to save a model which uses the `InputsEmbedding` layer. However, it's not working in with the actual model which I am trying to save and there's no indication where this tensor `77040:0` actually comes from.

Comment: I'm also trying to understand where does this `77040:0` comes from. How is implemented the input layer in the actual implementation? Is it exactly the same way as your test `inputs = layers.Input(shape=(None, num_features, num_channels))` ?

Comment: Yes. It's exactly the same. I wrote this unit-test just to compare and see whether or not this would crash too. To my surprise it's working. `InputsEmbedding` can do other things too e.g. `StackFrames` - this layer does not make any problems as well. The problem only occurs if I use the `ConvolutionStack` layer in `InputsEmbedding` but I can save both of them successfully in a standalone model.

Comment: Ok very interesting. Could you provide the config that actually reproduce the issue ?

Comment: It's complicated. This layer is just the first input-layer of a Transducer model which I am using for speech recognition. Unfortunately I cannot share this code. But it's so weird to see that everything seems to work fine except in this particular case where I need it to work..

Comment: I've just added the code of `ConvolutionStack` - I must be overlooking something but to me it looks like there are no temporary tensors or anything. I am going to debug this today again, your guess is probably right, but so far I just didn't see it. At the beginning I thought the problem might be return value of `ConvolutionStack. _new_convolution_block()` but all these tensors are tracked by Keras so this can't be the problem (also, the unit-test for saving that layer is working). And if the problematic tensor comes from outside, why can I safe the model if I remove the `ConvolutionStack`?

Comment: After a wild guess I was able to fix the problem ([see](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69086432/826983)). Thank you for helping me. I am going to accept my answer but I'll award you the bounty for helping me out :)

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution is to remove **slots** from the model

```
class ModelA(tf.keras.Model):
    # this model raises the error in the question
    __slots__ = ["model_layer"]
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.model_layer = layers.LayerNormalization()

    def call(self, inputs, training=None, mask=None):
        return self.model_layer(inputs)

    def get_config(self):
        return dict()


class ModelB(tf.keras.Model):
    # this model does NOT raise the error in the question
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.model_layer = layers.LayerNormalization()

    def call(self, inputs, training=None, mask=None):
        return self.model_layer(inputs)

    def get_config(self):
        return dict()
```

The same goes with custom layers in tensorflow 2.9.1 and python 3.7

Answer (score 0):

My case for being stuck with a `Tried to export a function which references untracked resource` assertion error was related to using `Lambda` layer to transform `Input`s prior to sending them to `TextVectorization`, while trying to use the [train/inference model pattern](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/preprocessing_layers#preprocessing_data_before_the_model_or_inside_the_model).

Concretely: My model uses `TextVectorization` layer, but the inputs are numeric (int64 IDs). Because the inputs are not strings, I need to pass them through `tf.strings.as_string(inputs)` prior to calling the vectorizer with those inputs. Long story short, this is easily solved using the `Lambda` layer. The issue is that when you export the inference model with the `Lambda` fronting the `TextVectorization` layer, you can no longer track the `TextVectorization` layer, which in turn, needs to store the vocabulary data in a Variable.

My solution: create a custom layer that wraps the `TextVectorization` layer (as is actually [recommended in the docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Lambda#variables))

```py
class NumericVectorization(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, vocab, output_sequence_length=1, name=None):
        super(NumericVectorization, self).__init__(name=name)
        self.vec = TextVectorization(
            standardize=None,
            split=None,
            output_mode='int',
            output_sequence_length=output_sequence_length,
            vocabulary=vocab
        )

    def call(self, inputs, *args, **kwargs):
        as_str = tf.strings.as_string(inputs)
        return self.vec(as_str)
```

Answer (score -1):

make sure to use all the packages with tensorflow.keras not keras

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).