# Tried to export a function which references 'untracked' resource Tensor("272554:0", shape=(), dtype=resource)

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, transformer-model, transfer-learning

I'm currently using CoAtNet0 for this project, and I can't seem to save the model. Hope someone can guide me how to fix the error or is there another way to save the model? The error for the code is:

> AssertionError: Tried to export a function which references
> 'untracked' resource Tensor("272554:0", shape=(), dtype=resource).
> TensorFlow objects (e.g. tf.Variable) captured by functions must be
> 'tracked' by assigning them to an attribute of a tracked object or
> assigned to an attribute of the main object directly.

Here's the code for the model.

```
# CoAtNet
class MBConv(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
def __init__(self, filters, kernel_size, strides = 1, expand_ratio = 1, se_ratio = 4, residual = True, momentum = 0.9, epsilon = 0.01, convolution = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D, activation = tf.nn.swish, kernel_initializer = "he_normal", **kwargs):
    super(MBConv, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    self.filters = filters
    self.kernel_size = kernel_size
    self.strides = strides
    self.expand_ratio = expand_ratio
    self.se_ratio = se_ratio
    self.residual = residual
    self.momentum = momentum
    self.epsilon = epsilon
    self.convolution = convolution
    self.activation = activation
    self.kernel_initializer = kernel_initializer
    self.model_layer = layers.LayerNormalization()

def build(self, input_shape):
    self.layers = []
    self.post = []
    if self.expand_ratio != 1:
        conv = self.convolution(input_shape[-1] * self.expand_ratio, 1, use_bias = False, kernel_initializer = self.kernel_initializer)
        norm = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(momentum = self.momentum, epsilon = self.epsilon)
        act = tf.keras.layers.Activation(self.activation)
        input_shape = input_shape[:-1] + (input_shape[-1] * self.expand_ratio,)
        self.layers += [conv, norm, act]
    
    #Depthwise Convolution
    conv = self.convolution(input_shape[-1], self.kernel_size, strides = self.strides, groups = input_shape[-1], padding = "same", use_bias = False, kernel_initializer = self.kernel_initializer)
    norm = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(momentum = self.momentum, epsilon = self.epsilon)
    act = tf.keras.layers.Activation(self.activation)
    self.layers += [conv, norm, act]
    
    #Squeeze and Excitation layer, if desired
    axis = list(range(1, len(input_shape) - 1))
    gap = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.reduce_mean(x, axis = axis, keepdims = True))
    squeeze = self.convolution(max(1, int(input_shape[-1] / self.se_ratio)), 1, use_bias = True, kernel_initializer = self.kernel_initializer)
    act = tf.keras.layers.Activation(self.activation)
    excitation = self.convolution(input_shape[-1], 1, use_bias = True, kernel_initializer = self.kernel_initializer)
    se = lambda x: x * tf.nn.sigmoid(excitation(act(squeeze(gap(x)))))
    self.layers += [se]
    
    #Output Phase
    conv = self.convolution(self.filters, 1, use_bias = False, kernel_initializer = self.kernel_initializer)
    norm = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(momentum = self.momentum, epsilon = self.epsilon)
    self.layers += [conv, norm]
    
    #Residual
    if self.residual:
        if 1 < self.strides:
            pool = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size = self.strides + 1, strides = self.strides, padding = "same")
            self.post.append(pool)
        if input_shape[-1] != self.filters:
            resample = self.convolution(self.filters, 1, use_bias = False, kernel_initializer = self.kernel_initializer)
            self.post.append(resample)
    
def call(self, x):
    out = x
    for layer in self.layers:
        out = layer(out)
        
    if self.residual:
        for layer in self.post:
            x = layer(x)
        out = out + x
    return out
    
def get_config(self):
    config = super(MBConv, self).get_config()
    config["filters"] = self.filters
    config["kernel_size"] = self.kernel_size
    config["expand_ratio"] = self.expand_ratio
    config["se_ratio"] = self.se_ratio
    config["residual"] = self.residual
    config["momentum"] = self.momentum
    config["epsilon"] = self.epsilon
    config["convolution"] = self.convolution
    config["activation"] = self.activation
    config["kernel_initializer"] = self.kernel_initializer
    return config

class MultiHeadSelfAttention(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
def __init__(self, emb_dim = 768, n_head = 12, out_dim = None, relative_window_size = None, dropout_rate = 0., kernel_initializer = tf.keras.initializers.RandomNormal(mean = 0, stddev = 0.01), **kwargs):
    #ScaledDotProductAttention
    super(MultiHeadSelfAttention, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    self.emb_dim = emb_dim
    self.n_head = n_head
    if emb_dim % n_head != 0:
        raise ValueError("Shoud be embedding dimension % number of heads = 0.")
    if out_dim is None:
        out_dim = self.emb_dim
    self.out_dim = out_dim
    if relative_window_size is not None and np.ndim(relative_window_size) == 0:
        relative_window_size = [relative_window_size, relative_window_size]
    self.relative_window_size = relative_window_size
    self.projection_dim = emb_dim // n_head
    self.dropout_rate = dropout_rate
    self.query = tf.keras.layers.Dense(emb_dim, kernel_initializer = kernel_initializer)
    self.key = tf.keras.layers.Dense(emb_dim, kernel_initializer = kernel_initializer)
    self.value = tf.keras.layers.Dense(emb_dim, kernel_initializer = kernel_initializer)
    self.combine = tf.keras.layers.Dense(out_dim, kernel_initializer = kernel_initializer)
    
def build(self, input_shape):
    if self.relative_window_size is not None:
        self.relative_position_bias_table = self.add_weight("relative_position_bias_table", shape = [((2 * self.relative_window_size[0]) - 1) * ((2 * self.relative_window_size[1]) - 1), self.n_head], trainable = self.trainable)
        coords_h = np.arange(self.relative_window_size[0])
        coords_w = np.arange(self.relative_window_size[1])
        coords = np.stack(np.meshgrid(coords_h, coords_w, indexing = "ij")) #2, Wh, Ww
        coords = np.reshape(coords, [2, -1])
        relative_coords = np.expand_dims(coords, axis = -1) - np.expand_dims(coords, axis = -2) #2, Wh * Ww, Wh * Ww
        relative_coords = np.transpose(relative_coords, [1, 2, 0]) #Wh * Ww, Wh * Ww, 2
        relative_coords[:, :, 0] += self.relative_window_size[0] - 1 #shift to start from 0
        relative_coords[:, :, 1] += self.relative_window_size[1] - 1
        relative_coords[:, :, 0] *= 2 * self.relative_window_size[1] - 1
        relative_position_index = np.sum(relative_coords, -1)
        self.relative_position_index = tf.Variable(tf.convert_to_tensor(relative_position_index), trainable = False, name= "relative_position_index")
    
def attention(self, query, key, value, relative_position_bias = None):
    score = tf.matmul(query, key, transpose_b = True)
    n_key = tf.cast(tf.shape(key)[-1], tf.float32)
    scaled_score = score / tf.math.sqrt(n_key)
    if relative_position_bias is not None:
        scaled_score = scaled_score + relative_position_bias
    weight = tf.nn.softmax(scaled_score, axis = -1)
    if 0 < self.dropout_rate:
        weight = tf.nn.dropout(weight, self.dropout_rate)
    out = tf.matmul(weight, value)
    return out

def separate_head(self, x):
    out = tf.keras.layers.Reshape([-1, self.n_head, self.projection_dim])(x)
    out = tf.keras.layers.Permute([2, 1, 3])(out)
    return out

def call(self, inputs):
    query = self.query(inputs)
    key = self.key(inputs)
    value = self.value(inputs)
    
    query = self.separate_head(query)
    key = self.separate_head(key)
    value = self.separate_head(value)
    
    relative_position_bias = None
    if self.relative_window_size is not None:
        relative_position_bias = tf.gather(self.relative_position_bias_table, tf.reshape(self.relative_position_index, [-1]))
        relative_position_bias = tf.reshape(relative_position_bias, [self.relative_window_size[0] * self.relative_window_size[1], self.relative_window_size[0] * self.relative_window_size[1], -1]) #Wh * Ww,Wh * Ww, nH
        relative_position_bias = tf.transpose(relative_position_bias, [2, 0, 1]) #nH, Wh * Ww, Wh * Ww
        relative_position_bias = tf.expand_dims(relative_position_bias, axis = 0)
    attention = self.attention(query, key, value, relative_position_bias)
    attention = tf.keras.layers.Permute([2, 1, 3])(attention)
    attention = tf.keras.layers.Reshape([-1, self.emb_dim])(attention)
    
    out = self.combine(attention)
    return out
    
def get_config(self):
    config = super(MultiHeadSelfAttention, self).get_config()
    config["emb_dim"] = self.emb_dim
    config["n_head"] = self.n_head
    config["out_dim"] = self.out_dim
    config["relative_window_size"] = self.relative_window_size
    config["projection_dim"] = self.projection_dim
    config["dropout_rate"] = self.dropout_rate
    return config

class ConvTransformer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
def __init__(self, emb_dim = 768, n_head = 12, strides = 1, out_dim = None, epsilon = 1e-5, dropout_rate = 0., activation = tf.keras.activations.gelu, kernel_initializer = tf.keras.initializers.RandomNormal(mean = 0, stddev = 0.01), **kwargs):
    super(ConvTransformer, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    self.emb_dim = emb_dim
    self.n_head = n_head
    self.strides = strides
    self.out_dim = out_dim if out_dim is not None else emb_dim
    self.epsilon = epsilon
    self.dropout_rate = dropout_rate
    self.activation = activation
    self.kernel_initializer = kernel_initializer
    
def build(self, input_shape):
    self.attention = []
    self.residual = []
    
    #Attention
    shape = input_shape[1:3]
    if 1 < self.strides:
        shape = np.divide(np.add(shape, (self.strides - 1)), self.strides).astype(int)
        pool = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size = self.strides + 1, strides = self.strides, padding = "same")
        self.attention.append(pool)
        self.residual.append(pool)
    if input_shape[-1] != self.out_dim:
        resample = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(self.out_dim, 1, padding = "same", use_bias = False, kernel_initializer = "he_normal")
        self.residual.append(resample)
    pre_reshape = tf.keras.layers.Reshape([-1, input_shape[-1]])
    mhsa = MultiHeadSelfAttention(emb_dim = self.emb_dim, n_head = self.n_head, out_dim = self.out_dim, relative_window_size = shape, dropout_rate = self.dropout_rate)
    post_reshape = tf.keras.layers.Reshape([*shape, self.out_dim])
    self.attention += [pre_reshape, mhsa, post_reshape]
    
    self.ffn = []
    #Feed Forward Network
    norm = tf.keras.layers.LayerNormalization(epsilon = self.epsilon)
    dense1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(self.out_dim, kernel_initializer = self.kernel_initializer)
    act = tf.keras.layers.Activation(self.activation)
    dense2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(self.out_dim, kernel_initializer = self.kernel_initializer)
    self.ffn = [norm, dense1, act, dense2]

def call(self, inputs):
    out = inputs
    for layer in self.attention:
        out = layer(out)
    for layer in self.residual:
        inputs = layer(inputs)
    out = out + inputs
    
    for layer in self.ffn:
        out = layer(out)
    return out
    
def get_config(self):
    config = super(ConvTransformer, self).get_config()
    config["emb_dim"] = self.emb_dim
    config["n_head"] = self.n_head
    config["strides"] = self.strides
    config["out_dim"] = self.out_dim
    config["epsilon"] = self.epsilon
    config["dropout_rate"] = self.dropout_rate
    config["activation"] = self.activation
    config["kernel_initializer"] = self.kernel_initializer
    return config

def coatnet(x, n_class = 1000, include_top = True, n_depth = [2, 2, 6, 14, 2], n_feature = [64, 96, 192, 384, 768], block = ["C", "M", "M", "T", "T"], stage_stride_size = 2, expand_ratio = 4, se_ratio = 4, dropout_rate = 0., activation = tf.keras.activations.gelu, name = ""):
#block : S > Stem, C > MBConv, T > Transformer
if 0 < len(name):
    name += "_"
if isinstance(stage_stride_size, int):
    stage_stride_size = [stage_stride_size] * len(block)
    
out = x
for i, (_n_depth, _n_feature, _block, _stage_stride_size) in enumerate(zip(n_depth, n_feature, block, stage_stride_size)):
    for j in range(_n_depth):
        stride_size = 1 if j != 0 else _stage_stride_size
        residual = out
        if _block.upper() == "C":# i == 0:
            out = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(_n_feature, 1 if i != 0 else 3, strides = stride_size, padding = "same", use_bias = False, kernel_initializer = "he_normal", name = "{0}stage{1}_conv{2}".format(name, i, j + 1))(out)
            out = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(momentum = 0.9, epsilon = 1e-5, name = "{0}stage{1}_norm{2}".format(name, i, j + 1))(out)
            out = tf.keras.layers.Activation(activation, name = "{0}stage{1}_act{2}".format(name, i, j + 1))(out)
        elif _block.upper() == "M":
            out = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(momentum = 0.9, epsilon = 1e-5, name = "{0}stage{1}_pre_norm{2}".format(name, i, j + 1))(out)
            out = MBConv(_n_feature, 3, strides = stride_size, expand_ratio = expand_ratio, se_ratio = se_ratio, residual = True, momentum = 0.9, epsilon = 1e-5, activation = activation, name = "{0}stage{1}_mbconv{2}".format(name, i, j + 1))(out)
        elif _block.upper() == "T":
            out = tf.keras.layers.LayerNormalization(epsilon = 1e-5, name = "{0}stage{1}_pre_norm{2}".format(name, i, j + 1))(out)
            out = ConvTransformer(32 * 8, 8, strides = stride_size, out_dim = _n_feature, epsilon = 1e-5, activation = activation, name = "{0}stage{1}_transformer{2}".format(name, i, j + 1))(out)

if include_top:
    out = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D(name = "{0}gap".format(name))(out)
    if 0 < dropout_rate:
        out = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(dropout_rate, name = "{0}dropout".format(name))(out)
    out = tf.keras.layers.Dense(n_class, kernel_initializer = tf.keras.initializers.RandomNormal(mean = 0, stddev = 0.01), name = "{0}logits".format(name))(out)
return out

def coatnet0(input_tensor = None, input_shape = None, classes = 1000, include_top = True, weights = None):
    if input_tensor is None:
        img_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape = input_shape)
    else:
        if not tf.keras.backend.is_keras_tensor(input_tensor):
            img_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(tensor = input_tensor, shape = input_shape)
        else:
            img_input = input_tensor

out = coatnet(img_input, classes, include_top, n_depth = [2, 2, 3, 5, 2], n_feature = [64, 96, 192, 384, 768], block = ["C", "M", "M", "T", "T"], stage_stride_size = 2, expand_ratio = 4, se_ratio = 4, dropout_rate = 0., activation = tf.keras.activations.gelu)
model = tf.keras.Model(img_input, out)

if weights is not None:
    model.load_weights(weights)
return model

def get_model():
model = coatnet0(input_shape = (224, 224, 3), include_top = False)

for layer in model.layers[:-1]:
    layer.trainable = False

#adding layers


x = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(model.output)
#x = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
#x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(500, activation = tf.keras.activations.gelu)(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(500, activation = tf.keras.activations.gelu, kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.VarianceScaling()`)(x)`

    #x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(x)
    #x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(500, activation = tf.keras.activations.gelu)(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(500, activation = tf.keras.activations.gelu, kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.VarianceScaling()
)(x)
    prediction = tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation = 'softmax', kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.VarianceScaling()
)(x)
    model = tf.keras.Model(model.input, prediction)

model.summary()

loss = tf.keras.losses.binary_crossentropy
opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.00001)

metric = ['accuracy']
#weights = compute_class_weight(class_weight = "balanced", classes = np.unique(train_batches.classes), y = train_batches.classes)
#cw = dict(zip(np.unique(train_batches.classes), weights))


callbacks = [
    #tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint("covid_classifier_model.h1", save_best_only=True, verbose = 0),
    tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(patience=10, monitor='val_loss', mode = "auto", verbose=1),
    tf.keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.1, patience=3, verbose=1, mode='auto')
    
]

model.compile(optimizer = opt, loss = loss,
              metrics=metric)
return model

model.save("my_model")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Your code formatting is broken. Can you please edit your question so that all code parts are formatted as code?

Comment: Hi! Sorry about that. I fixed it

Comment: Cool! If you find time you can share your solution here for others as an answer to your own question!

Comment: hahaha, I meant the formatting. Still having trouble with saving the model

Comment: Ah ok! Still it is not that easy to reproduce, because the code you provided is not a complete reproducible and minimal example. Did you check this post: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/57101 ?

Comment: Or this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69086432/18667225 ? Probably not ... but it is a nice example of how to reduce a case so that it is reproducible and minimal.